# scm:clearcase: and cruise control

Tags: clearcase, cruisecontrol, clearcase-remote-client

Can you please tell me requirement for integration of cruise control build integration tool (Java) and ClearCase client (CCRC 7.1).

**How to use `scm:clearcase:` command in a pom?

Is cleartool needed on the machine to execute scm command?**

Comment: In theory, it is possible to access CCRC views through the CM API, but I haven't tested it directly.

Answer (score 0):

CCRC is not a ClearCase client. It is a *remote* ClearCase Client: a GUI which will communicate with a CCRC server through web requests.

It has none of the executable found in a full ClearCase client installation, meaning is `scm:clearcase` (from the [Maven SCM implemantation ClearCase](http://maven.apache.org/scm/clearcase.html)) needs `cleartool.exe`, it won't work if you have only CCRC (and you can't have both CCRC and a full ClearCase client).

Comment: Hi, is it possiable to connect to clear client with use of ClearCase CM API throgh java code?

Comment: I thought its always possible for CCRC and CC client to co-exists? At least I have been using this setup for past 3 years...

Comment: @kolslorr: I always had trouble with CCRC7.1+ to run with a full CC client. Plus, all our clients who needs CCRC need it *because they don't want a full CC client*. Meaning in their configuration, they don't have all the executable associated with a full CC client. Even if they had, that wouldn't be useful, since they have no local CC view: only copy of web views which actually are on the CM CCRc server.